# Unable to reduce size in Adobe Premier Pro 2020

Tags: video, premiere, editing, adobe

Today, I've used Adobe Premier Pro 2020 for reducing a video size.

I have a video of size *400 MB* that I have imported into Adobe Premier to reduce its size.

[image: Exporting for reduction in size of video]

Here the estimated file size is shown is : *167 MB* but when I exported successfully with same settings the size of new video is *1 GB.*

**My questions are:**

1. **I'm unable to know — why it is not converting to the estimated size shown in the software, and how can I reduce the size without much reducing the quality of the video?**
2. **I wanted to know if Premier Pro is the best option to use to reduce file,  or some basic video editing stuffs or other software
   like Media Encode / After Effects is better?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen this behaviour before and it is possible that you are experiencing the same issue. With some GPUs, the hardware acceleration is buggy, so that the target and maximum bitrate is ignored. This also depends on the codec. As a workaround, in the export dialog, go to the Video tab and under Encoding Settings try to switch from "Hardware Encoding" to "Software Encoding". Now, the rendering will take a lot longer, but you should get a smaller file.

Try to update to the very latest version of Premiere and update the driver for your GPU. If this doesn't help, you cannot do much about it. You could try different codecs or stick with software encoding. Report the bug to Adobe and hope they can fix it some day.

Using Media Encoder won't help to fix that problem, however it's more convenient to send the render jobs to the queue of Media Encoder and let it work in the background. After Effects is specialized for animations and not well suited for general video editing.

Comment: Handbrake is good option for reducing size but other editing cannot be done with it .What have you tried about it to resolve this issue in Premier??

Comment: I've just seen it on someone's laptop. However, personally, I'm not affected by this, that's why I haven't taken action.